# OpenSUSE reinstall Yast

Tags: package-management, opensuse

I just can't understand what just happend?

I installed an openSUSE system, the original plan was to use it as an internal DNS Server for easyer access to all of the internal network computers. However something wasn't right with the dns server package, so I decided to remove it and install it again.

But after the removal something happened and the **yast**, **yast2** and **webyast** were also removed and I find myself now locked inside out! :S

The Package Manager from the desktop is also screwed it returns an `Failed to execute command package-manager --install %F` error message.

How can i reinstall the yast, I was googling but I couldn't find any info regarding this issue? All that I find is bunch of tutorials of how to use Yast.

**EDIT**
I just forgot to add that using `sudo zypper install yast2-gtk` is also out of the option since `zypper` has also been somehow mysteriously removed from my system :@

Comment: Congrats, you have trashed your system. Now you get to reinstall. Though you might want to figure out how you managed to remove those packages first, and avoid doing it again.

Comment: You can't be serious, there must be a way to reinstall the package manager...

Comment: `Though you might want to figure out how you managed to remove those packages first, and avoid doing it again.`
I was uninstalling the dns server package, and after that yast and zypper were gone :S

Comment: I'm serious enough to make a full answer out of it. Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to fix my system without reinstaling it.

Using the original installation image and performing and **upgrade install** fixed my system and after that zypper was installed again.

After that all I had to do was to reinstall the yast manager and the webyast service.

This way the job was done in an hour or so. 
If I was reinstalling again I would have lost days of reconfiguring the whole system.

Just for clarification of some things:
System: **OpenSUSE 12.1**
Desktop: **Xfce**

Comment: So you _did_ reinstall.

Comment: You may count my action into re installing, but under re install I assume full new fresh installation of the server along with all of the services hosted in it, and re configuring it all over again and then restoring the backups of the files and all that sh*t... This was a simple 5click procedure that saved me a lot of time and headache from my superiors...

Answer (score 0):

Congrats, you have trashed your system. Now you get to reinstall. Though you might want to figure out how you managed to remove those packages first, and avoid doing it again.

You might think I'm not serious and that there's some way to just reinstall the package manager. But if you've done something that destructive to your system, it's likely that much more than that is missing, and you won't be able to easily recover except via reinstalling.